# How to show an Error message on ag-grid react grid when an api call made using useQuery fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Cannot find any error message overly to tell users that api failed . I am using the Client Side Row model

Current I am only able to show the show no rows overlay  , but i want to show users an error message on the grid so they understand that the api has failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ag-grid only has two overlays - the 'loading' overlay, and the 'no rows found' overlay.

As far as I know, you can't add more overlays.

But you can customize the message on one of the existing ones, and use that instead.

See the "Custom Overlays" documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays